# when creating pdf from UIWebview app crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview, uigraphicscontext

I want to convert `UIWebview (height = 4224,width = 568)` into pdf to send it through mail,when I used below code app getting crashed in this line `([self.reportWebView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()])`.
Please give me some good suggestions.
Thank you.

```
    CGRect frame = self.reportWebView.frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [self.reportWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    self.reportWebView.frame = frame;

    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
    @autoreleasepool {
    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
         UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, self.reportWebView.bounds, nil);
         UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
         [self.reportWebView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
         UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
   }
```

Comment: What kind of crash? Is there an exemption?

Comment: Nothing is showing in the console,its showing a window that says "Connection Lost",Thats it

Comment: And this always happens when this code gets executed?

Comment: yes Exactly, @beyowulf.

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering the context in a wrong way.

Instead of

```
[self.reportWebView.layer UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

Try this

```
self.reportWebView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
```

Comment: Property 'renderInContext' not found on object of type 'CALayer *'